# fdisk command run on terminal but not run with ruby script

Tags: ruby, macos, system, popen

On my Mac OS X, I am trying to provide input to fdisk command via echo and Pipe Operator, And in this process i wants to provide bootable flag to partition number 1 of attached USB Drive and then i wants to quit with save, To achieve this I wrote following on Terminal:

```
 xxx-Mac:~xxx$ echo -e 'flag 1\nquit\nyes' | sudo fdisk -e /dev/disk2
```

I tried it, This works while i type manually on terminal but failed when i put it on script and use them.

I also got Successful Exit status for this command during script execution

I wrote that command on ruby script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

`echo -e 'flag 1\nquit\nyes' | sudo fdisk -e /dev/disk2`
```

What is the better way to write this so that command will work successfully wih save all the changes

Edit:

I got follwoing output when i tried by using suggested way on irb:

```
`echo -e 'flag 1\\nquit\\nyes' | sudo fdisk -e /dev/disk2`
"Enter 'help' for information\nfdisk: 1> Invalid command '-e'. Try 'help'.\nfdisk: 1>"
```

Comment: Are you really sure you want to answer unconditionally "yes" to fdisk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [`Open3::popen2`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen2) ?

```
require 'open3'

Open3.popen2('sudo fdisk -e /dev/disk2') { |i,o,t|
  i.puts 'flag 1'
  i.puts 'quit'
  i.puts 'yes'
  i.close
  p o.read
  t.join
}
```

Comment: @PradeepGupta, I updated the answer to use `Open3::popen2` instead of `Kernel::\``.

Comment: I am using variable to provide disk2 and in my case , I am using variable as @target = disk2, So how to provide variable here in place of disk2?

Comment: @PradeepGupta, Then replace `'sudo fdisk -e /dev/disk2'` with `"sudo fdisk -e /dev/#{@target}"`.